# How to install Ternjs for vim on Mac OSX?

Tags: javascript, macos, vim, npm, tern

I am trying to install [ternjs](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim) on vim.

I am on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

What did I do :

1.Install YouCompleteMe.

2.Install Nodejs v4.2.3 via the [pkg](https://nodejs.org/en/).

3.Run npm install in the tern_for_vim directory (nothing seems to happen).

```
gy@~/.vim/plugged/tern_for_vim$ npm install
gy@~/.vim/plugged/tern_for_vim$
```

4.Create a .tern-project file in my javascript application directory (which contains only on test.js file) :

```
$ cat .tern-project
{
    "libs": [
        "browser",
        "underscore",
        "jquery"
         ],
         "plugins": {
          }
}
```

5.Touch test.js with the demo code:

```
//Use ctrl-space to complete something
co
document.body.a

// Put the cursor in or after an expression, press ctrl-i to
// find its type

var fno = ["array", "of", "strings"]
var bar = foo.slice(0, 2).join("").split("a")[0]

// Works for locally defined types too.

function CTor() { this.size = 10 }
CTor.prototype.hallo = "hallo"

var baz = new CTor
```

6.Try to use :TernRename, :TernDoc..etc. Example of output for :TernRename

new name? fno urlopen **error [Errno 61] Connection refused**

What did I forgot?

Comment: Why don't you ask on the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl Do you mean on github?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the idea I just did that. I have never used this channel before.
https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim/issues/122